# How to split and copy the required number

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have tried to split the result and to print the number from result with the below code but it is not working, the code i have used being:

```
for count, item in enumerate(result):
   N=abs(int(repr(item).split(':')[-1].rstrip('}')))
print(N)
```

where

```
result={'PID': 7546982}
```

I would like to print only the number from result.

Pls help me with abv code, thanks in advance.

Agassi

Comment: expected output? and why is `N=result['PID']` not sufficient?

Comment: the expected output is N= 7546982

Comment: `result` is a dictionary or a string?

Comment: hi gboffi , its a string

Comment: in the above code, result is not a string but a dictionary. if it is a string, why do you iterate over it (why the for loop)?

Comment: Thank u Ayush Shanker N=result['PID'] is working enough

Comment: then result is NOT a string ... you should read some basic python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: This is the strangest way to access  dict I have ever seen

Answer (score 0):

Is result always a `dict` with only one key/value pair?

```
N = result.values().pop()
print(N)
```

Could result have multiple key/value pairs and you want to print the value of each one?

```
for N in result.values():
    print(N)
```